# How to load variables in powershell dynamically based on a selection

Tags: powershell

I am creating a powershell script that is going to be run on different environments. Therefore I am creating seperate variable files for each environment so that I can have one main script, and then as many environment scripts as required.

However I have been unable to get powershell to dynamically load my specific environment file

For testing purposes I have two files

env-CI.ps1
env-QA.ps1

both files only contain one variable 
[string] $envName = "CI"
and 
[string] $envName = "QA" respectively.

I am using a promptForChoice to specify what environment I with to work with, but I just cannot get the scripts to load.

I have read about dot but this does not appear to load the files

This is my script file

```
function whatEnvironment {
    [string] $answer = ""
    [string] $title = ""
    [string] $message = "What environment are you updating"

    $ci = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&CI", `
        "Update the CI environment."

    $qa = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&QA", `
        "Update the QA Environment."

    $uat = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&UAT", `
        "Update the UAT environment."

    $production = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Production", `
        "Update the Production Environment."
    $options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($ci, $qa, $uat, $production)

    :OuterLoop do 
        { 
            $answer = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, -1) 

            switch ($answer)
                {
                    0 {
                        . .\environment-CI.ps1  
                        break OuterLoop
                        }
                    1 {
                        . .\environment-QA.ps1  
                        break OuterLoop
                        }
                    2 {break OuterLoop}
                    3 {break OuterLoop}
                }
        }
    while ($y -ne 100)  
    return $answer
}

cls
$environment = whatEnvironment
write-host $environment
write-host $envName
```

No error is thrown, but the file containing the environment variables is not loaded.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just a scoping issue, the variables are only valid within the function where you dot source them. Try declaring them globally: `[string] $Global:envName = "CI"`

Comment: I have used global:, and it works. One things that makes me wary is that variables defined as global stay even after script execution. Therefore putting things on global always make me nervous and would prefer something else if available

Comment: While Ansgards answer definately is the nicer way to go about this: Try using `[string] $Script:envName = "CI"`. It might also work and not leave the variable after the script has run. Can't test it right now thou.

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing at a time. No weird breaking out of loops and stuff. Prompt for the user's decision first, then load the environment file *after* the user has made a valid choice.

```
function whatEnvironment {
    [string] $answer = ""
    [string] $title = ""
    [string] $message = "What environment are you updating"

    $ci = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&CI", "Update the CI environment."
    $qa = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&QA", "Update the QA Environment."
    $uat = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&UAT", "Update the UAT environment."
    $production = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Production", "Update the Production Environment."

    $options = [Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($ci, $qa, $uat, $production)

    do {
        $answer = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, -1)
    } until ($answer -in 1..4)

    switch ($answer) {
        0 { ". .\environment-CI.ps1" }
        1 { ". .\environment-QA.ps1" }
    }

    return $answer
}

$environment = whatEnvironment
Write-Host $environment
```